# Principal prime Ideals of height 1 and codimension 1 subvarieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ \mathfrak{p} $ be a prime ideal of $k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]. $ If $ \mathfrak{p} $ has height $1$, is this equivalent to saying that $ V(\mathfrak{p}) $ is of codimension $1$?

Assuming this is true, if $ \mathfrak{p} $ is principal, does it follow from this that the prime divisor $ D:=V(\mathfrak{p}) $ is principal since $ I(D) = (\mathfrak{p}) = (f) $ for some $ f \in k[x_{1},...,x_{n}]? $

Comment: You have an inclusion reversing correspondence between prime ideals of $A$ and closed irreducible subsets of $Spec(A)$, therefore saying that $V(I)$ is of codimension 1 is saying that chains of prime ideals contained in $I$ are ot length 1 at most, that is saying that $I$ is of height 1.

Comment: I don't really understand your second question. This is the definition of being principal, isn't it?

Comment: That's the definition of $ I(D) $ being principal(as an ideal), but I am wondering whether that is the same as saying that $ D $ is a principal divisor.

Comment: Well a principal divisor is a divisor of the form $div(f)$ for $f\in k(V)$ where $V$ is an integral subvariety of say an algebraic scheme $X$. Here, $div(f)=V(f)$.

Comment: This is the source of my confusion. Generally, $ div(f) = \sum_{i} v_{Y_{i}}(f) Y_{i}, $ where the sum is taken over the prime divisors of $ X. $ So I think I don't really understand the fact that the prime divisor $ D = V(f) $ is also the same as $ div(f). $ I think I was expecting $ div(f) $ to be a linear combination of all prime divisors of $X. $

Comment: What will be $v_Y$ in the case of $f$, for any $Y$ codimension 1 subvariety of the affine space that is not $V(f)$?